# dotenv values not loaded in nextjs

Tags: next.js, dotenv

I am struggling to load my `.env` file in my NextJS app.  Here is my code:

My `.env` is in root `/`
My `index.js` is in `/pages/index.js`

Here is my `index.js`:

```js
require("dotenv").config({ path: __dirname + '/../.env' })

import React, {Component} from 'react'
import Layout from '../components/layout'
import axios from 'axios'

class Import extends Component{

    uploadCSV = (evt) => {
        evt.preventDefault();

        const uploadURL = process.env.MY_UPLOAD_URL

        let data = new FormData(evt.target)

        axios.post(uploadURL, data, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        }).then((res) => {
            console.log(res)
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Layout title="Import Chatbot Intents" description="Import Chatbot Intents">
                    <form onSubmit={this.uploadCSV} name="import_csv" className="import_csv">
                        <h2>Import CSV</h2>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="csv_file">Upload file here: </label>
                            <input type="file" name="csv_file" id="csv_file" ref="csv_file" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <input type="hidden" id="customer_id" name="customer_id" ref="customer_id" value="1"/>
                            <button className="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </Layout>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Import
```

I observe that I can print out `.env` content in `render()` function, but I cannot do that in `uploadCSV` function.

For your info:

- using just `require("dotenv").config()` doesn't work
- using `require("dotenv").config({path: "../"})` doesn't work

**Updated**

My `env-config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
    'CSV_UPLOAD_URL': "http://localhost:3000/uploadcsv"
}
```

My babel.config.js:

```js
const env = require('./env-config')
console.log(env)

module.exports = function(api){

  // console.log({"process": process.env})
  api.cache(false)

  const presets = [
    "next/babel",
    "@zeit/next-typescript/babel"
  ]

  const plugins = [

      "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
      [
        'transform-define',
        env
      ]
  ]

  return { presets, plugins }
}
```

My `package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "Botadmin",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next -p 3001",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.1.5",
    "@zeit/next-less": "^1.0.1",
    "@zeit/next-typescript": "^1.1.1",
    "@zeit/next-workers": "^1.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "forever": "^0.15.3",
    "less": "^3.8.1",
    "multer": "^1.4.1",
    "next": "7.0.2",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "papaparse": "^4.6.2",
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "16.6.3",
    "typescript": "^3.1.6",
    "worker-loader": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-define": "^1.3.0",
    "dotenv": "^6.1.0",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^0.4.15"
  }
}
```

The Error:

> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-babel-loader.js):
>
> TypeError: Property property of MemberExpression expected node to be of a type ["Identifier","PrivateName"] but instead got "StringLiteral"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to use [env in Nextjs](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/with-universal-configuration)

1. Install `babel-plugin-transform-define`
2. create the env-config.js file and define your variables

   ```
   const prod = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
   module.exports = {
    'process.env.BACKEND_URL': prod ? 'https://api.example.com' : 'https://localhost:8080'
   }
   ```
3. Create the .babelrc.js file

   ```
   const env = require('./env-config.js')

   module.exports = {
    presets: ['next/babel'],
    plugins: [['transform-define', env]] 
   }
   ```
4. Now you have access to the env in your code

   ```
    process.env.BACKEND_URL
   ```

Alternatives: [next-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-env)

Comment: i think your babel configuration is wrong,  I made a codesandbox  to show you ;) https://codesandbox.io/s/jl560l17ww

Comment: Your sandbox failed to compile.  Did I miss anything?

Comment: fixed, something weird happened.

Answer (score 6):

As of Next.js 9.4, there is a built-in solution for setting environment variables https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables

Comment: BUYER BEWARE the next.js environment only supports "development" via `next dev` and "production". You cannot perform anything other than a production build with next.js environments - you may have more flexibility with the Vercel cloud but you have to pay for that.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for @Alex for the answer.  Another way to solve the same problem is to install `dotenv-webpack` using `npm install -D dotenv-webpack`.

Once installed.  edit `next.config.js`:

```
require('dotenv').config()
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack')

const path = require('path')

const withTypescript = require('@zeit/next-typescript')
const withWorkers = require('@zeit/next-workers')
const withLess = require('@zeit/next-less')

module.exports = withWorkers(withLess(withTypescript({
    context: __dirname,
    generateEtags: false,
    entry: './pages/index.js',
    distDir: 'build',
    pageExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx'],

    cssModules: false,

    webpack: (config, options) => {

        config.plugins = config.plugins || []

        config.plugins = [
            ...config.plugins,

            // Read the .env file
            new Dotenv({
                path: path.join(__dirname, '.env'),
                systemvars: true
            })
        ]

        // Fixes npm packages that depend on `fs` module
        config.node = {
            fs: 'empty'
        }

        return config
    }
})))
```

Comment: Not sure why, but this one just doens't work when I try to run next build in gitlab ci, for example. The .env is there, locally it works and there...it is just empty if I try to console.log in next.config.js file. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm a bit late, but, you can just install dotenv and use it inside of your ***next.config.js*** file

```
require("dotenv").config();

const environment = process.env.NODE_ENV || "dev";
```

Answer (score 2):

if you need to replicate next.js env loading in other files (setupTests.ts, next-logger.config.js) do this:

```
const { loadEnvConfig } = require('@next/env')

loadEnvConfig(__dirname, true, {
  info: () => null,
  error: console.error,
})
```